# General problem Euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, quadrilateral

> Let $\square ABCD$ be a square of side-length $a$, and consider also the circle with diameter $\overline{AC}$. Let $E$ be a point on $\stackrel{\frown}{BC}$ of the circle, and let $K$ a point on $\overrightarrow{EC}$ such that $|\overline{AE}|=|\overline{EK}|$.
>
> $i)$ Why does $|\overline{DK}|=a$?
>   $ii)$ Let $J=\overleftrightarrow{AE}\cap\overleftrightarrow{DC} $. Prove that $\triangle ADJ$ and $\triangle CEJ$ are similar.
>   $iii)$ Let $ L= \overleftrightarrow{AK}\cap\overleftrightarrow{DE} $. Prove that $L$ is in an arc that you will determine.

I've tried doing it , and the only thing that I've got is that $\angle AEK =90 $, but I can't move foward.
Edit:I figured it out $ii)$, but I´m still stucked in $i)$ and $iii)$

Comment: Is $\overline{\rm EC}$ the line segment [EC] (not the arc ?) Is $d(.,.)$ Euclidean distance ?

Comment: Yes and to the second question I only know one kind if distance, so I suppose so

Comment: You are right, I didn´t know the correct notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$\alpha = \alpha’$ (because AD = DC).

By SAS, $\triangle EAD \cong \triangle EKD$. Hence, $DK = DA = a$.

AS for (iii), we have sufficient info from  the above to say that $\angle ELK = 90^0$. Hence, L is part of a circle (ELK, say).

Comment: Your answer is so simple but so enlightening! That was what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why $\alpha = \alpha ' $. What does AD = DC has to do with it?

Comment: @Impropio Both AD and DC are **equal** chords of the same circle. Since AD and DC are respectively subtended by $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ at the circumference, therefore $\alpha = \alpha'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AE\cap BD=\{G\}$, $AE\cap BC=\{F\}$, $AK\cap BD=\{M\}$ and $AK\cap DC=\{N\}$.

Thus, since $$\measuredangle GAN=\measuredangle FBM=\measuredangle LDN=\measuredangle CKM=45^{\circ},$$
we see that $ABFM$, $AGND$ and $CMDK$ they are cyclic.

From the first and the second quadrilateral we obtain $$\measuredangle FMA=\measuredangle FGN=90^{\circ},$$ which says that $GFCNM$ is cyclic.

Now, let $\measuredangle ECB=\alpha$.

Thus, $$\measuredangle DCK=90^{\circ}-\alpha,$$
$$\measuredangle BAG=\measuredangle ECB=\alpha,$$
$$\measuredangle AGM=\measuredangle ABG+\measuredangle BAG=45^{\circ}+\alpha,$$
which says $$\measuredangle MGN=\measuredangle AGM-\measuredangle AGM=90^{\circ}-(45^{\circ}+\alpha)=45^{\circ}-\alpha.$$
Thus, $$\measuredangle MKD=\measuredangle MCD=\measuredangle MGN=45^{\circ}-\alpha,$$
which says $$\measuredangle CKD=\measuredangle CKM+\measuredangle DKM=45^{\circ}+45^{\circ}-\alpha=90^{\circ}-\alpha=\measuredangle DCK,$$
which gives $$DK=a.$$

ii) is true because $$\measuredangle CEJ=\measuredangle ADJ=90^{\circ}.$$

iii) Since $$DK=a=AD,$$ we obtain that $L$ is a midpoint of $AK$ and $ED\perp AK$.